# Nestjs: inject provider into objects created by the key word new

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I am trying to inject a provider to objects created by `new`. Is it possible? For example:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
}

export class SomeObject {

@Inject()
service: SomeService;
}

let obj = new SomeObject();
```

It's not working in my tests, the `obj.service` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the dependency injection system will only work with objects that are created with it.
You can create `SomeObject` as a [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#use-factory) though, e.g. with `useClass`:

```
@Injectable()
class SomeObject {
  constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}
}

@Module({
  providers: [
   SomeService,
   { provide: SomeObject, useClass: SomeObject },
  ],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

or with `useFactory` for custom setup logic:

```
const someObjectFactory = {
  provide: 'SomeObject',
  useFactory: (someService: SomeService) => {
    // custom setup logic
    return new SomeObject(someService);
  },
  inject: [SomeService],
};

@Module({
  providers: [SomeService, connectionFactory],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

Comment: I am trying to implement the image kit nodejs library in nestjs and though I know that it must be done with a custom provider, I have not been able to implement it.
Hoping to get an answer to this 

import ImageKit from 'imagekit';

const imageKitFactory = {
  useFactory: () => {
    return new ImageKit({
      privateKey: 'private_T',
      publicKey: 'public_',
      urlEndpoint: 'https://ik.imagekit.io',
    });
  },
  inject: [],
};
@Module({
  controllers: [ImagekitController],
  providers: [ImagekitService],
})
export class ImagekitModule {}